# Project management software that syncs with smartphone?

Tags: windows, calendar, project-management

I went through the archives here and the Wikipedia page on [Project management software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_project_management_software), but didn't find information on this type of application to manage projects:

- Native Windows application (don't like web-based solutions; prefer native to cross-platform)
- Free or affordable, ie. not an Enterprise solution
- Scalable from one to a few concurrent users
- Like MS Projet et al., a project consists in tasks which can be further divided into sub-tasks, and the whole thing is displayed in an tree list:

  [image]
- An item that has a date set (either start/due) must be [displayed in a Calendar view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGHrg.jpg), so it's easy to know what work must be done each day
- The Calendar view must somehow sync with smartphones (at least BlackBerry)

  [image]
  At this point, the apps I know either don't provide a Calendar at all, or do but they can't sync with smartphones, which forces me to copy/paste scheduled items into Outlook so they are synced with my BlackBerry :-/

---

Edit: I'm thinking of something like [The Calendar Planner](http://www.thecalendarplanner.com/demo/TCP_Demo_shortlr.html), but with the added feature of syncing with the Calendar/Schedule of a BlackBerry

Answer (score 1):

Ruling out web based solutions is a mistake here. You are asking for features that are only being developed for web based solutions. Project management is a collaborative app, one that is has proven not to work that well as a stand alone in the enterprise. It's like asking for a hybrid car with a carburetor.

Answer (score 1):

While it is still a web app, you should look at [activeCollab](http://www.activecollab.com/). It's similar to Basecamp, but since you can install it on your own server, you could set it up on your system locally.

There is also an iPhone app that interfaces with it, [Coolab](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/coolab/id377339889?mt=8). Though, you'd need to be running activeCollab on a machine that the iPhone could interface with via the internet.

Again, like gcycle7 has said, project management apps are more and more moving to web-based soultions. It gives more flexibility and makes it possible to sync with a smartphone in real-time.

Answer (score 0):

I think basecamp is what you might be looking for. http://basecamphq.com/
There is a beta out for the blackberry.

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer a Windows app rather than an online application.

Answer (score 0):

A web-based solution via your BB browser is probably the simplest way to meet most of your requirements - asking for a cheap, native app with BB integration is really limiting your options.

That said, I think [Clarizen](http://www.clarizen.com) are working on an iPhone integration with BB to follow.

Answer (score 0):

If your blackberry can handle ical files then I think most applications will be able to export tasks in that way.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I guess there's no Windows project management application that includes a calendar/contacts, and can sync with smartphones.